# C compiler flag to ignore sign

Tags: c, char, sign, compiler-flags

I am currently dealing with code purchased from a third party contractor. One struct has an unsigned char field while the function that they are passing that field to requires a signed char. The compiler does not like this, as it considers them to be mismatched types. However, it apparently compiles for that contractor. Some Googling has told me that "[i]t is implementation-defined whether a char object can hold negative values". Could the contractor's compiler basically ignore the signed/unsigned type and treat them the same? Or is there a compiler flag that will treat them the same?

C is not my strongest language--just look at my tags on my user page--so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What compiler? Most [if not all] C compilers will allow you to change the implicit signedness of a char, but it's a compiler-specific flag, so there's no generic answer.

Comment: this guy: http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3567/cc_options.html

Comment: Why don't you have them cast to the correct type as needed?

Comment: this code is from a contractor who has yet to answer my calls. it is supposed to work, especially since we were given a built package--that's unusable for other reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are three different types. From the standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1990):

> 6.1.2.5 Types
>
> ...
>
> The three types **char**, **signed char** and
>   **unsigned char** are collectively called
>   the *character types*.

(and in C++ for instance you have to (or at least should) write override functions with three variants of them if you have a char argument)

Plain char might be treated signed or unsigned by the compiler, but the standard says (also in 6.1.2.5):

> An object declared as type **char** is
>   large enough to store any member of
>   the basic execution character set. If
>   a member of the required source
>   character set in 5.2.1 is stored in a
>   **char** object, its value is guarantied
>   to be positive. If other quantities
>   are stored in a **char** object, the
>   behavior is implementation-defined:
>   the values are treated as either
>   signed or nonnegative integers.

and

> An object declared as type signed char occupies the same amount of storage as a ''plain'' **char** object.

The characters referred to in 5.2.1 are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, space, tab, newline and the following 29 graphic characters:

```
! " # % & ' ( ) * + , - . / :
; < = > ? [ \ ] ^ _ { | } ~
```

### Answer

All of that I interpret to basically mean that ascii characters with value less than 128 are guarantied to be positive. So if the values stored always are less than 128 it should be safe (from a value preserving perspective), although not so good practice.

Comment: this chunk of code deals with images, so i suspect that there are more than 'A's and 'b's being stored there.

Comment: problem was solved. apparently the possible values were 0-100 and we had received mixed versions. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is compiler-dependent. For example, in VC++ there's a compiler option and a corresponding _CHAR_UNSIGNED macro defined if that option instructs to use unsigned char by default.

Comment: i figured we were using different compilers. that's a real problem, because installing a new one here could take forever, if not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you're talking about fields of type `signed char` and `unsigned char`, so they're explicitly wrong.  If one of them was simply `char`, it might match in whatever compiler the contractor is using (IIRC, it's implementation-defined whether `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`), but not in yours.  In that case, you might be able to get by with a command-line option or something to change yours.

Alternatively, the contractor might be using a compiler, or compiler options, that allow him to compile while ignoring errors or warnings.  Do you know what sort of compilation environment he has?

In any case, this is not good C.  If one of the types is just `char`, it relies on implementation-defined behavior, and therefore isn't portable.  If not, it's flat wrong.  I'd take this up with the contractor.